# Bernstein-Sato polynomial

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, d-modules

Let $f$ be a polynomial. It is well-known that there exits a polynomial $b_f(s)$, such that $P\cdot f^{s+1}=b_f(s)f^s$ for some differential operator $P$. The polynomial $b_f(s)$ has been studied very intensively, and in many cases $b_f(s)$ are known.  Here is my question: is there any algorithm to write down a such differential operator $P$? I'm more interested in quasi-homogeneous polynomial.

Comment: Yes, though I’m not sure what the algorithm is off the top of my head. One can compute these using Macaulay2

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take a look at the Toshinori Oaku's article "An algorithm of computing b-functions" (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077241952). This has exactly what you're looking for. You may also want to take a look at my advisor Uli Walther's survey "Survey on the $D$-module $f^s$" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.07516).